# Finding which template a custom block is using

Tags: magento

I am trying to figure out which template the following block is using to generate custom links. How would I know which template it is when there is no template path defined for the block? Thanks for any pointers!

```
<block type="page/template_links" name="top.links.custom" as="topLinksCustom">
```

Answer (score 1):

The template is `page/template/links.phtml`.
Usually when a block does not have a template specified in the layout file, it's either a `core/text` block that does not use a template or the template is specified in the block constructor. If you take a look at `Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links::_construct` you should see this:

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->setTemplate('page/template/links.phtml');
}
```

This is the template you are looking for.
And other easy way would be to turn on the template path hints.

Comment: Hi Marius, thanks. I had checked template path hints actually, but this was just pointing to `frontend/base/default/template/page/template/links.phtml` - whereas there must be a customisation happening somewhere and it's not within the custom template directory being used by the site. It's a multi-store site with different languages and I'm just trying to figure out how these top links are managed/differentiated for each store.

Comment: @bsod99, css maybe, or different settings from the layout? The `link.phtml` template is a general one for rendering links. But the links that are added in there can have different classes and other settings.

Comment: Top links block renders links in `<li>` as well as child blocks. If you aren't finding what you expect in the top links template, you can head to any child block & template which it is rendering.